# Write Query Based on Two Tables That Returns Number of Orders From Each Customer Grouped by Email

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sql-order-by

I'm trying to write a query that considers the following tables that will return the number of orders submitted by each customer, grouped by their email.

Ex: john.smith@email.com | 23

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymVcS.png)

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(Order ID), Customer.Customer email
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customer ON Customer.Customer ID = Orders.Customer ID
GROUP BY Customer.Customer email
ORDER BY COUNT(Order ID)
```

I'm really struggling with SQL JOINS. Can anyone help me grasp this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a customer table where each row refers to a specific customer.
You have an order table where a customer can have multiple orders.

When you `join` these two tables, that is, each row of the customer table is joined to each row of the order table that has a single customer ID.

For example, if a customer has two orders, he will be linked to the order table twice. Your table has a `one-to-many` relationship.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT C.CustomerID, COUNT(*) FROM Customers C, Orders O
WHERE C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerID
```

I tried the above query in [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc) and looks like it worked.

I believe that in your case you'll need to change the C.CustomerID of the SELECT and the GROUP BY to your email like C.email

```sql
SELECT C.CustomerEmail, COUNT(*) FROM Customers C, Orders O
WHERE C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
GROUP BY C.CustomerEmail
```

If your Customer table allows that the same email can be from multiple IDs, you're going to have some consistency problems in this report.